# How to place svg inside a circle with background using css?

Tags: css

i have an svg and i want it to be inside a circle. Basically a check svg with green background in circle shape. Something like in the image.

[image]

What i have tried?

```
<Svgcheck className="fill_check" width="28" height="28"/>

.fill_check {
    fill: white;
 }
```

Could someone tell me how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.

Is that what you want?

(I'm sorry for using img-tag but you have not provided an svg)

```css
#svg {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/White_check.svg/2000px-White_check.svg.png" id="svg" class="circle" />
```

To make the background (behind the check mark) green you just put a green background on the element.
To have a more extended green that goes beyond the edges of the checkmark you have to put a border with the same color as the background

Comment: thanks for the answer :) i meant the final output should be like the one in the image provided in the question. the svg is just a check mark in grey i have to add strokes to it somehow which i am unaware of how to do.